# How to authenticate Microsoft Dynamics CRM from office 365 login user in azure hosted web api?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, office365, azure-active-directory

I have created WebApi and hosted it to Azure server, now I want to get data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM into this API with logged in Office 365 users credentials.

So when I call the WebApi from office 365 it takes Office 365 logged in user's credentials and get data from CRM of same user.

Answer (score 2):

For getting Dynamics 365 data you need the access token which as you mentioned is granted by office 365 [OAuth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2013/12/12/use-oauth-to-authenticate-with-the-crm-service/) server. Assuming that you already registered your app in Azure active directory and gained your client Id and secret key, you need also give permission to your app to access Dynamics 365 (using Required permissions in Setting panel of app registration).

After setting up your app in Azure AD, then you can redirect your user to office 365 login page (OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint) for getting the access token. there are different methods to do it. In my experience I used getting token using Authentication code, but generally you need to compose a url to login page with following param:

```
'https://login.windows.net/' + tenant + '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&state=<state>&resource=<resource>'
```

In case of  Authentication code it returns a code which you can use to acquire token. Microsoft developed some drivers which does it for you. If you use `node.js` you can check out [adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs), for sure they have something similar for dot.net.

After getting your access token, you just need to call your Dynamics 365 (resource) to get the data.